# GROUP BY give priority to in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have the following query.

```
$query_assignments = "SELECT * FROM tb_scheduler_assignments 
                      WHERE company_id = '".$company_id."' OR 
                      dept_id = '".$dept_id."' OR 
                      user_id = '".$user_id."' ORDER BY 
                      due_date GROUP BY purchase_id";
```

What I'd like is a single query solution that would keep the results for `user_id` over `dept_id` and `dept_id` over `company_id`.

For example:

- if the same `purchase_id` occurs for
  rows that were gotten via `dept_id` and
  `user_id`, then I only want the result
  for the `user_id`;
- if the same `purchase_id` occurs for
  rows that were gotten via `company_id`
  and `user_id`, then I only want the
  result for the `user_id`

Answer (score 1):

First, you're interpolating variables in your SQL, which suggests you might be vulnerable to SQL injection. Just to make sure. PHP should offer prepared statements, or some escaping function.

Second, your SQL statement won't compile because you're using `GROUP BY a` but selecting `*` which includes at least three more columns.

Third, it sounds like you're misunderstanding SQL in thinking that it might, in a query such as you're trying to formulate (without `UNION ALL`), retrieve duplicate rows, i.e. the same row multiple times because it matches multiple criteria. This is not so.

Comment: `select * … group by` will work in MySQL. the returned row for the ungrouped rows is undefined, but usually the first one found

Comment: @knittl - You're right, this will "work" in MySQL. It'll even allow you to force a min or max value to show up in one of the colums by specifying an unrelated `ORDER BY`. Neat hack indeed. :-/

Comment: thanks for the response and sorry for the delay in my response.  You're right on the points above. I'll post what i ended up doing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The "single query" solution that I was looking for doesn't seem to exist, or if it does, it would be way slower than just handling all the sorting in php.
So, I ran 3 separate queries, put each of them into arrays, and then in order to put them all into a final array with the hierarchy that I needed, I did the loops below to see if the purchaseID existed for the levels up the hierarchy. If it didn't, then I put it in to the array.

```
$finalArray = array();
foreach ($companyArray as $purchaseID => $companyData) {
    if (empty($deptArray[$purchaseID]) && empty($userArray[$purchaseID])) {
        $finalArray[] = $companyData;
    }
}
foreach ($deptArray as $purchaseID => $deptData) {
    if (empty($userArray[$purchaseID])) {
        $finalArray[] = $deptData;
    }
}
foreach ($userArray as $purchaseID => $userData) {
    $finalArray[] = $userData;
}
```

Then I can sort that array however I want and loop through that to echo what I need to.
Not sure if that's the best way, but it worked well and is lightning fast for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query_assignments = "SELECT *,
                      IF(user_id = {$user_id}, 30,
                        IF(dept_id = {$dept_id}, 20,
                          IF(company_id = {$company_id}, 10, 0)
                        )
                      ) as priority
                      FROM tb_scheduler_assignments 
                      WHERE company_id = {$company_id} OR 
                      dept_id = {$dept_id} OR 
                      user_id = {$user_id}
                      GROUP BY purchase_id
                      ORDER BY due_date, priority DESC";
```

You can make a virtual field with the `if` statement.

```
user_id:      30 pts
dept_id:      20 pts
company_id:   10 pts
else:          0 pts
```

**WARNING: can not be Indexed!**

Syntax FIX: `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` reordered